# Splitting a string in JSON and using them in two separate tds with angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

So I'm calling a JSON string, and I want to split it in two at the ":" and use the two values to show in two separate td tags.

```
function testCtrl($scope) {
$scope.response = {"name":["The name field is required."],"param":["Hobby: Coding", "Country: USA"]};}
```

to visualize a little more at what I'm trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/8mnxLzc1/5/

Comment: Why trim it? it works as you use it in your fiddle.. you don't need `TrimColon`

Comment: @RazvanBalosin Oops I meant to take that out, it's something that I need to do for my project, I have JSON data which need to show in a table, but the values and their descriptions are in one string, just like I have shown, I'm trying to figure out how I can split the string and show the value and description in two separate table columns

Comment: What you did there was good.. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgx5zp9w/3/)

Comment: If this is because of bad design at the source... fix the source

Comment: @charlietfl You're completely right! I wish I could fix the source, unfortunately I can't.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="resp in response.param">
        <td ng-repeat="val in resp.split(':')">{{ val }}</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mnxLzc1/6/)

Comment: Hmm, this seems to work, but say I want to move "Hobby" into a separate td and "Coding" into a separate one. How would that be possible to do with the code over here

Comment: they would be in separate td's using the above code .. I have added a border to the table in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mnxLzc1/7/) - it might look clearer that way..

Answer (score 0):

This is a entirely angular solution, no need to call the function split in the ng-repeat.

https://jsfiddle.net/kLjzh565/

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="resp in response.param track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="i in [$index]">
            {{response.param[i]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```